# How to play the video files in a SD_card in a Loop by using Android APP?

Tags: android, android-layout, video, apk, android-video-player

In the android application by using this code.
`video_player_view.set Video Path("/SD_card/video.mp4")`

- we can play only one video from this code
- I what to play the multiple videos from the SD_card in a loop one by one.
  suppose i had a 5 videos in a SD_card.My app must  detect the SD_card and it should play the video one by one in a loop. 
  How it can be done?

Comment: The first solution I see. It's read one by one. You will create a list of files. But, I feel the fallen fluidity. My second solution. If the files are small. You must bind them into a single.